# Как сделать плавную анимацию при скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать чтобы при скролле вниз плавно применялась анимация top.? сейчас это с задержкой. Логика такая: при прокрутки на 1px блок двигается вниз на 10px.

При скролле на 1px блок .q2 смещается на 10px. Т. е. при прокрутки на 4 px блок .q2 смещается на 40px

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
 if($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).scrollTop()-1){
 $('.q2').animate({
    top: "+=10"
  });}
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 1000px;
}
.q1{
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  position: relative;
}
.q2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: gray;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="q1">
    <div class="q2">465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    <span>465645</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что это за сравнение ? `if($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).scrollTop()-1)`

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan Ну если опустился на 1 пиксел то...

Comment: вы как будто делаете следующее которое всегда даст правильный результат -- `if(x > x-1)`

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan Ну это понятно, просто суть в том чтобы плавный переход был. А все нюансы я потом исправлю

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS ваше "условие" всегда выполняется, поэтому в нем нет смысла

Comment: По умолчанию duration у `animate` 400 ms. Для 10px это будет выглядеть достаточно неплавно.

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS ты подробно скажи при скролле у какого блока какая анимация должна быть, в вопросе напиши

Comment: При скролле на 1px блок .q2 смещается на 10px. Думаю понятно

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll',function(event){
  delta = parseInt(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail);
 if(delta < 0){
    $('.q2').animate({
      top: parseInt($('.q2').css('top'))+10+'px'
    },10);
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 1000px;
}
.q1{
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  position: relative;
}
.q2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: gray;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="q1">
    <div class="q2">465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    465645<br>
    <span>465645</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот пример реализации анимации, рассчитываем скролл вверх или в низ, и если в низ то делаем анимацию.